# How to do validate confirmaion in multistep form if confirmation field on next step?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic, client-side-validation, multi-step

I use `client_side_validations-formtastic` and `client_side_validations` gems.

In my model:

```
validates_presence_of :full_name, :parent_name
validates_confirmation_of :full_name, :parent_name, on: :create
```

In form

```
= semantic_form_for @attendee ||= Attendee.new, validate: true do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :full_name, label: "Attendee Full Name", validate: { confirmation: false }
    = f.input :parent_name, label: "Parent/Guardian Name", validate: { confirmation: false }
    = link_to image_tag("buttons/save.png"), "#new-attendee-confirm", id: "new_attendee_save", class: "fancybox"
    #new-attendee-confirm{:style => "width:600px;display: none;"}
      = render partial: "attendees/new_attendee_confirm", locals: {f: f }
```

new_attendee_confirm

```
= f.input :full_name_confirmation, label: "Attendee Full Name"
= f.input :parent_name_confirmation, label: "Parent/Guardian Name"
= f.action :submit
```

On `#new_attendee_save` I added script for multistep form validation (it works if I remove `validates_confirmation_of` from model):

```
$("#new_attendee_save").bind("click", function (e) {
  //If the form is valid then go to next else don't
  var valid = true;
  // this will cycle through all visible inputs and attempt to validate all of them.
  // if validations fail 'valid' is set to false
  $('[data-validate]:input:visible').each(function () {
    var settings = window.ClientSideValidations.forms[this.form.id]
    if (!$(this).isValid(settings.validators)) {
      valid = false
    }
  });
  if (valid) {
    //code to go to next step
  }
  // if any of the inputs are invalid we want to disrupt the click event
  return valid;
});
```

I need this logic. User fills out the form the first step, which triggered all validation except confirmation.
Next the user clicks on the save button, it shows some agreement and as a signature is prompted to enter the name of the child and the parent. In these fields validations should work for presence and confirmation.
Is there any way to implement this scenario?

In my way if I add `validate: { confirmation: false }` to first step it does not work and still shows message doesn't match confirmation.